# ReactJS starterkit stuck on basic example

Tags: function, reactjs, render

I want to learn ReactJS by following this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/learning-react-getting-started-and-concepts?utm_content=buffer7a560&utm_medium=social&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_campaign=buffer). Although I'm not able to run the Hello World example in my browser.

I try running the following code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dev ReactJS</title>

    <!-- <script src="build/react.js"></script> -->
    <script src="build/react-with-addons.js"></script>
    <script src="build/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="mount"></div>
    <script type="text/jsx">
        /** @jsx React.DOM */
        React.render(
            React.DOM.h1(null, 'Hello, world!'),
            document.getElementById('mount')
        );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Which generates the error shown below:

```
Uncaught TypeError: React.render is not a function - Inline JSX script:3
```

I've read some things about changes made in v0.14, but I'm using the starter kit including v0.11. I'm uploading to my website trough FTP, or is it necessary to run on, for example, a NodeJS server? I can't find anything about that..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure why you commented out react.js file

Comment: Because I've tried to make it work using react-with-addons.js (which seems to me to be the same as react.js but with some extra addons). With only using react.js I've got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

That article was written in 2014, There have been lots of changes in the react ecosystem. This guide [react-howto](https://github.com/petehunt/react-howto) by Pete Hunt will prove useful in your journey into the sometimes overwhelming react ecosystem

Comment: Thanks for the howto page. Hopefully this information is correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Because tutorial too old, new versions of React.js doesn't contain render, instead you have to use react-dom. See details on  [official Facebook page (with examples)](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html)

Comment: As told in my question I've did some research. The ReachtDOM function is available since version 0.14, instead I'm using the reactjs starter kit which contains v0.11.

Comment: Oh. sorry i missed this. But, i resolved problem) Look in comments to this article author changed from React.renderComponent to React.render - https://scotch.io/tutorials/learning-react-getting-started-and-concepts?utm_content=buffer7a560&utm_medium=social&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_campaign=buffer#comment-1829509930

React 0.11.2 doesn't have an render, only renderComponent, try to change.